# Banners clutter search engine results

Tags: bug, notification-bar, search-engine

I am not sure under which exact circumstances this happens, but when doing a Google search this morning for [`"Warning: use -cacerts option to access cacerts keystore"`](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22Warning%3A+use+-cacerts+option+to+access+cacerts+keystore%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8%60) I noticed that banners, like the current invitation to take the Developer Survey, clutter the search results in Google:

[image]

My SEO experience is very limited but I think it should be possible to omit this.

Comment: That's some major search result pollution!

Comment: This only seems to happen on PC; it [doesn't happen on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14EWI.jpg).